# How to make chrome history in HUD bigger?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, hud, google

I was looking for a way to enlarge the history - section in the HUD (alt-menu), so that it displays more items from the history and items from longer ago.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change this setting yet... :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the HUDs options as yet. However, the HUD learns from your usage, and you can move between items by using the arrow keys, so if you keep using it over time it will get to your common sites faster.